# Selection using wildcards

Tags: arcgis-10.3, select-by-attribute

How can I use wildcards (*) in the ArcGIS Query Builder? It cannot refine my work in Select By Attribute function.

```
'AA03-FE-P006R'
'AA03-FE-P007R'
'AA03-FE-P006L'
Right (Asset_Code,1) = 'L'
```

This returns the following error:

There was a problem selecting
An invalid SQL statement was used.

Is there a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to specify the exact ArcGIS product (ArcMap/Pro), license level, whether you are using the GUI or Python, the data source format, the column datatype, your exact query, and the error message or other result.

Answer (score 2):

Try Like operator:

```
Asset_Code LIKE '%L'
```

[image]